# jQuery compare multiple classes and loop through class name

Tags: jquery

I have to compare css properties from a combination of multiple classes.

I have a few class names which i can store it in array.

```
var classLoop = [ class-a, class-b, class-c  ];
```

and how to run this array loop in a if statment ?

```
     if ($('.class-x.class-loop').css('margin') == '0') {            
        //do something
     }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **[`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** to iterate the array and do the comparison inside the loop.

```
var classLoop = ["class-a", "class-b", "class-c"];

$.each(classLoop, function(index, val){
    if ($("." + val).css("margin") == "0") {
        // code goes here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @rahul but I needed to compare 2 classes nevertheless this is a great idea.

I just added the class name before the array loop.

```
var classLoop = [ 'class-a', 'class-b', 'class-c' ];

        $.each('.class-1'+classLoop, function(index, val){
            if ($(this).css("margin") == "0") {
                // code goes here
            } 
        });
```